# ruby on rails 4.0 link issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

In my views/contracts/index.html.erb page I am trying to insert a link to my view/task_orders/index.html.erb page. I put this line in my views/contracts/index.html.erb page:

```
<%= link_to 'Task Orders', task_orders %>
```

but I keep getting the error:

undefined local variable or method `task_order' for #<#

Can someone please help me understand what's going on?

Thanks!!

Comment: The mandatory link to [Rails Guides on Links](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-links)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Task Orders', task_orders_path %>
```

And just a small correction, you don't insert links to views, but to controller/action, and in the action you render a view.

Comment: my routes.rb page says:

resources :task_orders

Comment: Ok, edited out the non-relevant part then. This should work or something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried <%= link_to 'task orders', '/task_orders/index' %> and it worked!

Comment: just try to run **rake routes** and check whether             task_orders GET    /task_orders(.:format)                             task_orders#index exists for it